# Как передать Command от Button в другую ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Всем привет,

Я новичек в MVVM и возникли проблемы
Как передать команду в другую ViewModel и что бы там вызвался определенный метод у меня это перевод текста из TextBox-ов.

В прикрепленном скриншоте у меня при выборе из Combobox-a загружается определенный UserControl по центру далее я вбиваю туда инфу и нажимаю на кнопку внизу для перевода.
Проблема в том что эта кнопка привязана к MainViewModel а не к текущей ViewModel(CertificateViewMode)

[image: Интерфейс]

Даже не знаю что выкладывать по коду, его так дофига для одной этой проблемы.

Постараюсь самое важное только выложить.

Кнопка в интерфейсе

```
<Button
       x:Name="Btn_Translate"
       Grid.Column="1"
       Height="Auto"
       Command="{Binding TranslateCommand}"
       Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
       ToolTip="Перевести текст">
           <materialDesign:PackIcon
                        Width="35"
                        Height="Auto"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Foreground="DarkKhaki"
                        Kind="Translate" />
</Button>
```

Основная Вьюшка в конструктор передается коллекция UserControl-ов которые уже с генерировались в App.xaml.cs

```cs
 public MainViewModel(IEnumerable<ITemplate> modules)
{
    this.OpenFolderTemplate = new RelayCommand(this.OpenFolderAndLoadTemplate);
    this.Templates = modules.OrderBy(m => m.Name).ToList();
    if (this.Templates.Count > 0)
    {
       this.SelectTemplate = this.Templates[0];
    }
}
private RelayCommand TranslateCommand { get; set; }

public List<ITemplate> Templates { get; private set; }

//Выбор UserControl в Combobox-e
public ITemplate SelectTemplate
{
     get
     {
       return selectedTemplate;
     }
     set
     {
        if (value != selectedTemplate)
        {
           if (selectedTemplate != null)
           {
              selectedTemplate.Deactivate();
           }
           selectedTemplate = value;
           selectedTemplate.RelayCommand = TranslateCommand;
           OnPropertyChanged("SelectTemplate");
           OnPropertyChanged("UserInterface");
        }
     }
}
```

Вот еще что связано с этим

Сам интерфейс шаблона, сюда я добавил только RelayCommand

```cs
 interface ITemplate
    {
        string Name { get; }
        UserControl UserInterface { get; }
        RelayCommand RelayCommand { get; set; }
        void Deactivate();
    }
```

Класс который реализует интерфейс ITemplate

```cs
abstract class TemplateBase : ITemplate
    {
        private UserControl view;

        protected abstract UserControl CreateViewAndViewModel();

        public abstract string Name { get; }

        public abstract RelayCommand RelayCommand { get; set; }

        public UserControl UserInterface
        {
            get
            {
                if (view == null)
                {
                    view = CreateViewAndViewModel();
                }
                return view;
            }
        }

        public void Deactivate()
        {
            if (view != null)
            {
                var d = view.DataContext as IDisposable;
                if (d != null) d.Dispose();
                view = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Доп класс который уже загружает указанны UserControl и Вьюшку

Birth_Certificate() это уже класс во ViewModel

```cs
 class Birth_CertificatePlugin : TemplateBase 
    {
        protected override UserControl CreateViewAndViewModel()
        {
            return new Birth_Certificate() { DataContext = new Birth_CertificateView(RelayCommand) };
        }

public override RelayCommand RelayCommand
        {
            get => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            set => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override string Name
        {
            get { return "Справка о рождении"; }
        }
    }
```

Хотел сделать что то типа того при выборе SelectTemplate контрола

```cs
selectedTemplate.RelayCommand = TranslateCommand;
```

Но он на этапе компиляции начинает ругаться NotImplementException();

Это студия сама мне с генерировала.

```cs
public override RelayCommand RelayCommand
        {
            get => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            set => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Хочет что бы я что то в геттере и сеттере седлал но я не понимаю что.
Не понимаю как выбраться из этой проблемы, я запутался.
Может вообще все удалить и сделать по другому.

Comment: могу github ссылку скинуть для простоты

Comment: У вас ваша команда там же, где `SelectTemplate`, какие проблемы его использовать?

Comment: Там же, и как его использовать ? Я могу его использовать но как. Что добавить надо в интерфейс ITemplate что бы можно было выполнять команду перевода. Класс перевода у меня в модели висит. Я там пытался вот добавить Relaycommand типа хотел через него вызвать метод внутри той ViewModel

Comment: Или пойти от обратного, как из выбранной ViewModel вытащить все поля обратно что бы можно было в основной ViewModel выполнить метод перевода

Comment: В Классе перевода грубо говоря есть 1 метод  List<items> GetTranslate(object[] fields), где fields это поля которые нужно перевести

Comment: Ваша первая проблема в том, что ваша ViewModel почему то знет о UserControl

Comment: Эту навигацию я взял из [opensource Naudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudioWpfDemo/MainWindowViewModel.cs) Сейчас уже не соображаю завтра попробую чистую навигацию сделать в новом проекте и может придумаю что нибудь